# Изменение содержимого в TableViewCell

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

У меня есть кнопка "PLAY" в каждой секции, после нажатия на нее проигрывается аудио, пытаюсь сделать изменение картинки в кнопке "PLAY" на секции после нажатия, но как? Как изменять содержимое в уже созданной ячейке?

В **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
texturl = cell.message.text;
[cell.playbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(playaudio) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Сам  void:

```
-(void)playaudio
{

    [***СЮДА НАДО cell.playbutton, но как****** setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSURL *urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:texturl];
    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:urlStream];
    [player play];
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за все подсказки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[cell.playbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(playaudio:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)playaudio:(UIButton *)button 
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSURL *urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:texturl];
    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:urlStream];
    [player play];
}
```

**Обновление**

Проверьте, чтобы место, куда вы помещаете изображение, было одним и тем же. Например:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
             forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо. Но старая картинка кнопки остается, а новая поялвется поверх старой, как быть?)

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы место куда вы помещаете изображение было одно и тоже.
Например: 
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
             forState:(UIControlState)state

Comment: Место одно и то же, даже с setBackgroundImage сменил на setImage при установке и изменении изображения, не помогло.

Comment: @An0nimchic Покажите весь код cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы сразу не присвоить кнопке разные изображения для разных состояний? И в

```
 -(void)playaudio:(UIButton *)button 
{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    if(button.selected)
    //проигрываем аудио
    else
    //останавливаем воспроизведение
```